I need to find the value of the potentiometers R9 and R8 to transform an input signal but I am at a loss and need an explanation as to how this works


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The goal of this circuit is to transform a 0-1V signal into a 4-20 mA signal.

If you are a beginner you may need some more help. Q1 and Q3 are a current mirror. Q4 and the network around it is an adjustable current source. The op amp and Q5 is a precision current source or voltage to current converter.

The base and collector of Q3 need to be "shorted". R9+R10=266 Ohm, R7+R8=1k225.
